# PostgreSQL расширения

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Хочу установить расширение PostGis для работы с геометриями, но pgAdmin4 не содержит такого расширения. А команда `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` выдает следующую ошибку - ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
SQL-состояние: 58P01

Использую mac на m1. Буду рад любому ответу

Answer (score 0):

Мне удалось решить свою проблему. Дело в том что postgis установил свои контролы совершенно не в ту папку, откуда postgres их пытался взять. Из папки postgis скопировал контролы и переместил в папку для postgres. Вопрос решил